# large rails application boot time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I have a very very large rails application and I've read every post there on how to reduce boot time, each suggesting to cut down on models or controllers or gems, but all of them are being used.

Problem i'm facing is that heroku pushes R10 error code since my app takes more than 60s to load.

I've been trying one thing, almost successfully. I'm trying to run Bundler.require and Application.inialize! in threads (latter thread waiting on the first one to finish). Advantage of this being that thin server boots almost instantly.

Problem is, when someone hits the app with a request, the initialization process stays incomplete. Any idea how i can achieve this?

Comment: Can you elaborate on "the initialization process stays incomplete"? Do you mean the initialization just never completes? Or is some "initialized" variable not being set? Are you getting an error?

Answer (score 0):

You can take control of the initialization process by extending the `initialize!` method in `config/application.rb`.

Look at this [sample `application.rb` file](https://github.com/RailsApps/rails-devise-roles/blob/master/config/application.rb) from a github project. You should be able to extend the `initialize!` method inside of the `class Application < Rails::Application` scope.

You can take the base methods from the [Rails Initialization docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/initialization.html) in section 2.3 railties/lib/rails/application.rb. So here is what you'll have if you extend the methods and leave them as they are implemented by default.

```
class Application < Rails::Application
  def initialize!(group=:default) #:nodoc:
    raise "Application has been already initialized." if @initialized
    run_initializers(group, self)
    @initialized = true
    self
  end

  def run_initializers(group=:default, *args)
    return if instance_variable_defined?(:@ran)
    initializers.tsort_each do |initializer|
      initializer.run(*args) if initializer.belongs_to?(group)
    end
    @ran = true
  end
end
```

At this point you can add print statements and determine which piece you're getting stuck on. For example, is your `@initialized` variable never being set to `true`? If so, why? Perhaps you are getting stuck inside of `run_intializers`. If that is the case, then which initializer are you getting stuck inside of?

Answer (score -1):

I've realized what i'm trying to do is not possible. So i'm ending the thread.

What i'm doing:
In my environment.rb,

```
def init_bundler

  # If you want your assets lazily compiled in production, use this line
  s = Time.now
  _rails_groups = (ENV["RAILS_GROUPS"]||"").split(",")
  if _rails_groups.length == 1 and _rails_groups.first.to_s == "assets"
    Bundler.require(:assets)  #load ONLY assets .. 
  elsif _rails_groups.length == 1 and _rails_groups.first.to_s == "clock"
    Bundler.require(:clock)  #load ONLY assets .. 
  else
    Bundler.require(:default, *_rails_groups, Rails.env.to_s)
  end
  puts "bundler required in #{Time.now - s}s"
end

puts "starting t1"
$_t1 = Thread.new{ init_bundler }
```

In my environment.rb:

```
def init_app
  # Initialize the rails application
  puts "initialize started"
  s = Time.now
  Hedgepo::Application.initialize!
  puts "initialize done in #{Time.now - s}s"

end

puts "starting t2"
$_t2 = Thread.new do 
  loop do 
    if defined?($_t1) and !$_t1.status
      init_app
      break
    else
      puts "waiting for bundler"
    end
    sleep(1)
  end
end
```

the middleware i'm using above everyone else:

```
class MyInit
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    loop do 
      if defined?($_t2) and !$_t2.status
        break
      else
        puts "waiting for app init to finish...."
      end
      sleep(1)
    end
    @app.call(env)
  end
end
```

But the problem is that Rack::Server allocates an 'app' variable and .start!s the server when the hit comes. So whatever I do, i cannot change the app that was initialized BEFORE this @app variable was populated.

Comment: You can override any process you want to, it's Ruby, that is the beauty of it. All you need to do is find out where `@app` is being assigned and extend the method like I did in my answer. It's very simple to take control of these initialization features.

Comment: Also, your answer really isn't solving anything. All you do is call the default methods manually. You need to access the scope of the methods rather than simply calling them.